# Method definition for 'addTask:' not found

Tags: objective-c

I was making a program called iTahDoodle when i got an error, My error is "Method definition for 'addTask:' not found"

Here is my code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// Helper function to fetch the path to our ro-do data stored on disk
NSString *docPath()
{
    NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathList objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.td"];
}

@implementation AppDelegate

#pragma mark - Application delegate callbacks

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //attempt to load an existing to-do dataset from an array stored to disk
    NSArray *plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:docPath()];
    if (plist) {
        //if there was a dataset available, copy it into our instance variable
        tasks = [plist mutableCopy];
    } else {
        //otherwise, just create an empty one to get us started.
        tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }

    //create and configure the uiwondow instance
    //a cgrect is a struct with an origin (x,y) and size (width,height)
    CGRect windowFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIWindow *theWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:windowFrame];
    [self setWindow:theWindow];

    //define the frame rectangles of three UI elements
    //CGrectMake () creates a CGRect from (x,y, width, height}
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 380);
    CGRect fieldFrame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 200, 31);
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(228, 40, 72, 31);

    // create and configure the table view
    taskTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame
                                             style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [taskTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    //create and configure the text field where new tasks will be typed
    taskField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:fieldFrame];
    [taskField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [taskField setPlaceholder:@"Type a task, Tap Insert"];

    // create and configure a rounded rect insert button
    insertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [insertButton setFrame:buttonFrame];

    //buttons behave using a target/action callback
    // configure the insert button's action to call this object's -addTask: method
    [insertButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(addTask:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //give the button a title
    [insertButton setTitle:@"Insert"
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // add our three ui elements to the window
    [[self window] addSubview:taskTable];
    [[self window] addSubview:taskField];
    [[self window] addSubview:insertButton];

    // finalize the window and put it on the screen
    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

I believe that is all the code you will need to see, but if it isn't add a comment.

Comment: You don't show an implementation of an `addTask:` method ... maybe the error is telling the truth.

Comment: Your addTask method needs to look like this: `- (void)addTask:(id)sender`, `- (void)addTask` will not work

Comment: I have that already in my .h file

Comment: You can declare it in your .h file. I am not sure but I think you could even implement it in your .h file. However, that was quite unusual. And if you did then the compiler would not throw that error. I, too, think that the compiler is just right. You simply did not implement an `addTask:` method. Have a look on what Mike said. In Objective-C `addTask` is different from `addTask:. The difference is that the one with the colon receives an agurment and the other does not.

Comment: The fact that you declared it in your header just proofs it. If you did not declare it in your header but didn't implement it at all, then the error message would be different from what you got. It would be "No visible interface of ... declares the selector ..." or so.

Comment: So do what? My .h says "- (void)addTask:(id)sender"

Comment: So how do I implement it?? I think it is in the code

Comment: You don't need the `addTask:` declaration in your .h file. You need to add the actual implementation in your .m file.

Comment: And why are you creating all of this UI code in the app delegate method? You should create a view controller that has all of the code for the views and the logic to process the UI interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the method in your .m file.